# How to change internal IP address from DHCP to static?

Tags: command-line, server, ifconfig

I have a pc running Ubuntu server 14.04.1. The internet was set up using DHCP I believe. I want to keep the same IP and subnet I have now but just change it to static for the internal IP.

Comment: Are you getting DHCP from your router or your ISP?

Comment: @Mitch, the router I would imagine is handling the DHCP, couldn't say for sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to go by the classical interfaces file configuration, /etc/network/interfaces.

Edit the file:

```
sudo su
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Its content is invariably the following lines:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

And then the ethernet device, eth0 in this case, with the following lines:

Ip by dhcp:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

To switch to static IP, knowing the parameters in use by ifconfig, you must place similar lines to these:

```
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.10.0
    broadcast 192.168.10.255
    gateway 192.168.10.1
```

Of course you should change the values ​​for your network.